# Absoluteness of $\Delta_0$ formulas for Boolean-Valued models.

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I am stuck on the following lemma from Jech's forcing chapter and need a little bit of help.

---

> Lemma. *If* $\varphi(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ *is a* $\Delta_0$ *formula, then*
>   $$\varphi(x_1, \dots, x_n) \hspace{0.5cm} \leftrightarrow \hspace{0.5cm} \|\varphi(\check{x}_1, \dots, \check{x}_n)\| = 1.$$

---

Now i have proved this for atomic formulas by a simultanious induction on both $x \in y$ and $x = y$. The connectives are easy. But i'm stuck on the existential quantifier. The $(\exists y \in x)\varphi(y) \rightarrow \|(\exists y \in \check{x})\varphi(y)\| = 1$ part is relatively easy. But the converse seems a little bit tricky. I have tried to use the fact that $V^B$ is full but that doesn't guarantee that the element that we get by eliminating the quantifier is a set in $x$.
 Any hints or answers would be very helpful. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but that doesn't guarantee that the element that we get by eliminating the quantifier is a set in $x$.

It's easier to approach this from a slightly different angle:
$$
\begin{align*}
1 & = \| \exists y \in \check{x} \phi(y, \ldots) \| \\
&= \sum_{y \in \mathrm{dom}(\check{x})} \check{x}(y) \cdot \| \phi(y, \ldots) \|
\end{align*}
$$

Now recall that

1. $\check{x}(y) \in \{0,1\}$ for all $y \in \mathrm{dom}(\check{x})$ and
2. $\mathrm{dom}(\check{x}) = \{ \check{y} \mid y \in x \}$.

Puzzle this together to conclude that there is some $y \in x$ such that
$$
1 = \| \phi(\check{y}, \ldots) \|,
$$
as desired.

Comment: Going with this approach, we know that we have defined $\check{x}$ such that for all $y \in x$ we have $\check{x}(\check{y}) = 1$ and we know for any $y \in \text{dom}(\check{x})$, there is a $t \in x$ such that, $\check{t} = y$, so plugging this in our sum we have: $ 1 = \sum_{\check{t} \in \text{dom}(\check{x})}\|\varphi(\check{t}, \dots)\| $. But here how can we argue the existance of an element of $x$ such that $\|\varphi(\check{t}, \dots)\| = 1$?

Comment: There is a mistake in your comment. You have $1 = \sum_{\check{y} \in \mathrm{dom}(\check{x})} \check{x}(\check{y}) \cdot \| \phi(\check{y}, \ldots) \|$. Since $\check{x}(\check{y})  \in \{0,1\}$ there must be some $\check{y} \in \mathrm{dom}(\check{x})$ such that $\check{x}(\check{y}) = 1$ as otherwise $\sum_{\check{y} \in \mathrm{dom}(\check{x})} \check{x}(\check{y}) \cdot \| \phi(\check{y}, \ldots) \| = \sum_{\check{y} \in \mathrm{dom}(\check{x})} 0 \cdot \| \phi(\check{y}, \ldots) \| = 0$.

Comment: But Jech defines $\check{x}(\check{y}) = 1$ for all $y \in x$. Even if what i'm saying is wrong then how do we get rid of the supremum.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri Oh, sorry. I was a bit confused about what you'd said. You're totally right: Now apply the induction hypothesis to see that $\| \phi(\check{y}, \ldots ) \| \in \{0,1\}$ for all $y \in x$. Since the suprema of all of them is $1$, one of them has to be $1$ as well (by a calculation similar to the one in my previous comment).

Comment: Oh, thanks, seems it wasn't that tricky after all.